# K-shortest path between two points in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, network, road, shortest-path, qgis-network-analysis

I am new to QGIS. I have a road network layer in QGIS. I can compute the shortest path between the two points over the road network layer via the Network Analysis toolbox in QGIS.

I am interested in generating k-shortest paths between two points. I would like to ask if QGIS offers this functionality or is it possible to use additional Plugins/Python scripts to do the job.

Comment: Have you tried looking at pgRouting? This uses a fairly comprehensive list of functions based on time or distance.

Comment: Perhaps [`v.net.path`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.net.path.html) can be useful